# Unexpected result in MyISAM when grouping by bit and selecting distinct values

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, myisam

We have a MyISAM table with a single column `bit` and two rows, containing `0` and `1`. We group by this column, make a count and select it. The result as follows is expected.

```
select count(         bit), bit from tab GROUP BY bit;

| count(bit) | bit |
|------------|-----|
|         1  |   0 |
|         1  |   1 |
```

But when using the `distinct` keyword, the output value of the column is always `1`. Why?

```
select count(distinct bit), bit from tab GROUP BY bit;
| count(bit) | bit |
|------------|-----|
|         1  |   1 | # WHYYY
|         1  |   1 |
```

I've been crawling the documentation and the internet but with no luck.
Here is the setup:

```
CREATE TABLE `tab` (
  `bit` bit(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; # When using InnoDB everything's fine

INSERT INTO `tab` (`bit`) VALUES
(CONV('1', 2, 10) + 0),
(CONV('0', 2, 10) + 0);
```

---

PS: One more thing. I've been doing several experiments. Using `group_concat`, the column `bit` becomes independent again.

```
select count(distinct bit), group_concat(bit) from tab GROUP BY bit;
| count(bit) | bit        |
|------------|------------|
|         1  | 1 byte (0) |
|         1  | 1 byte (1) |
```

Comment: The code works correctly on the version of MySQL used on rex tester (http://rextester.com/VDEMJ16162).    This sounds like a bug, given that you've tested on the two storage engines and you are seeing a difference.

Comment: Is this relevant: https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/04/11/bit-values-in-mysql/

Comment: @GordonLinoff , the code doesn't work correctly. If I select `count(!distinct! bit)`, it returns the same unexpected result as here.
@Strawberry, I've been googling for DISTINCT and GROUP BY issues, not for BIT issues. Thanks. Would you then recommend me to use `tinyint(1)` instead of `bit` for ever?

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: Same behaviour at:
* mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407
* mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.30-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comments, I am from now on convinced of not using the bit column at all. The more reliable alternative is `tinyint(1)`.

Inspired from the Adminer application bit handling, I recommend using `bin` function to cast bit on an expected value every time when selecting:

```
select count(distinct bit), BIN(bit) from tab GROUP BY bit;
```